# Formulate edit distance as matrix multiplication

Tags: python, nlp, linear-algebra, edit-distance

I am computing a weighted edit distance between two strings using a slight modification of the Levenshtein distance where I use context-specific edit operation probabilities. Unlike the standard Levenshtein that only considers the best sequence of edit operations, here, I am interested in a sum of costs of possible edit operation sequences transforming one string into another.

For two strings `s1` and `s2`, I have a cost tensor of shape `len(s1)` × `len(s2)` × 3 with costs that correspond to doing deletion, insertion respectively. For simplicity, both strings start with a technical start symbol which stands for an empty string.

```py
deletion_id = 0
insertion_id = 1
substitute_id = 2

alpha = np.zeros((len(s1), len(s2))
alpha[0, 0] = 1.0

for t, _ in enumerate(s1):
    for v, _ in enumerate(s2):
        if v >= 1:
            alpha[t, v] += costs[t, v, insertion_id] * alpha[t, v - 1]
        if t >= 1:
            alpha[t, v] += costs[t, v, deletion_id] * alpha[t - 1, v]
        if v >= 1 and t >= 1:
            alpha[t, v] += costs[t, v, subsitute_id] * alpha[t - 1, v - 1]
```

The sum of probabilities of all possible ends up in `alpha[len(s1) - 1, len(s2) - 1]`.

The nested for loops very much resemble the definition of matrix multiplication. Vectorization of the computation could speed things up, but I did not figure out how to reformulate this using matrix multiplication. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to mention a quick flaw in your above code: Is it intended that there is several additions for a single element, if both `v` and `t` are true?

Comment: No, the conditions are not mutually exclusive. Levenshtein distance assumes every string has a technical start that you cannot delete (therefore `t >= 1`), cannot insert elsewhere (`v >= 1`) and cannot substitute. At other positions, all three operations are possible and want to sum their probabilities.